# NoMethodError: undefined method `marshal_dump' for #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000000006fcbba0>

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-on-rails-6.1, ruby-2.7

We use below ruby and rails version -

Ruby 2.7.3 Rails 6.1.3.2

While creating a new user it throws the below error -

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `marshal_dump' for #ActiveModel::Errors:0x0000000006fcbba0 Did you mean? marshal_load):
app/controllers/user_controller.rb:33:in `create'
```

Below Create method defined in the controller -

```
def create

   @user = User.new(user_params)

   respond_to do |format|
   if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
   else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
 end
```

Comment: Which line in your quoted source code is line 33? In any case, you don't show any code which appears to call `marshal_dump`. Please investigate further by checking the call location in the full stack trace to identify the code location which tries to call this method. Likely it is related to either the session store or some cache.

Comment: Just a guess. If you use `awesome_print` with `pry-rails`,  `awesome_print` prevents the proper error messages. https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print/issues/413